# How can I determine PD for given impulse, based on transient thermal impedance for BJT?

Tags: bjt, ltspice, thermal, power-dissipation

I have (selected) a BJT to work with rectified mains application.
Transistor is PBHV9560Z (600 V, 0.5 A PNP)
https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PBHV9560Z.pdf

Under normal operation conditions, this BJT can dissipate 0.5W without heatsink. Maximum current should be 0.5A.

One thing is not clear to me, I have a pulse of 9.64W (average) for about 100ms. Current is well in range but due to VCE of 260V, power reaches this level.

[image]

I'm not sure this is OK or not because datasheet don't specify a digested SOA (like for MOSFETs or other BJTs).

How can I estimate maximum allowable PD based on given transient thermal impedance for my case of 100ms?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this graph and assuming the duty cycle is low (say 0.05) then, the transient thermal impedance for 100 ms is 20 K/W: -

[image]

That means it would warm by 400 K (in 100 ms) and that would be unacceptable by a mile. Even if the duty cycle were virtually zero, the impedance would only drop to about 12 K/W at 100 ms and it would still warm by 240 K.